# How to include a php file with the highest id?

Tags: php

So, what I'm trying to do is pretty much the same as what [this website does](http://www.boreme.com) each posting is given an id, and the posting with the highest id is displayed first, then the posting with the second highest is displayed second, etc, etc...

Is it something like;

```
<a href="posting.php?id=<?php echo max(*something goes here*) ?>
```

Any help appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably something that you should be doing in your SQL when you are fetching the data from the database. You can do it quite easily using an `order by` statement in your query like this:

```
select 
    postID, 
    postTitle, 
    postAuthor 
from 
    posts 
where 
    someCondition=something 
order by 
    postID desc
```

In this way, you are already pulling the data out of the database without having to do any ordering or structuring in your PHP code - the database will be more efficient than PHP for this.

Comment: The above reply outlined this quite adequately however I just wish to emphasize that the actual operational part the OP is looking for in this is the ORDER BY command.

Comment: @Shane Not to be rude, but the only other answer here at the moment talking about ordering in the database was posted three minutes after this one?

Comment: @Shane I posted an answer saying that ordering this would be much more efficient inside the database rather than in PHP itself and showed an example of how to do it via a SQL query. I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: I was not asking a question, rather pointing out that the command the OP is looking for from your snippet is the ORDER BY command - just enforcing for clarity is all.

Comment: @Shane Oh okay, got me confuddled is all :)

Answer (score 0):

The website you have linked to does not use PHP to generate the ID. They grab the posts from a database and order them by descending date.

If you do not have a database, or want to do it in PHP, you would do this I guess:

```
$idlist = array(1,2,3,4,5,6); // Array of IDs, grabbed from wherever.
rsort($idlist); // Sort the array in reverse order.
$idlist[0] // Grab the first in the array to have the biggest.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display like last 10 posts , so all what you have is to get posts ordered by post id
for example

```
SELECT * FROM posts order by post_id DESC limit 10;
```